# Ember error saying I specified a hasMany when I haven't

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Totally at a loss here with this attempted Ember 1.2 app. I've formatted the JSON according to how Ember likes it and I've followed all the instructions in the guide for setting up my model but I'm getting some weird errors.

Here's my JSON:

```
{ "candidates" : [ { "id" : 796,
    "name" : "Townsend, Matt",
    "party" : 7
  },
  { "id" : 797,
    "name" : "Griffiths, Robert",
    "party" : 54
  },
  { "id" : 795,
    "name" : "Burke, George",
    "party" : 11
  },
  { "id" : 794,
    "name" : "Zeigler, Simon",
    "party" : 4
  },
  { "id" : 793,
    "name" : "Aslam, Farida",
    "party" : 10
  },
  { "id" : 792,
    "name" : "Hannigan, Dominic",
    "party" : 3
  },
  { "id" : 791,
    "name" : "Hoare, Simon",
    "party" : 1
  },
  { "id" : 798,
    "name" : "Brennan, Kevin",
    "party" : 2
  },
  { "id" : 803,
    "name" : "Griffiths, Jake",
    "party" : 7
  },
  { "id" : 802,
    "name" : "Henessey, Mike",
    "party" : 4
  },
  { "id" : 801,
    "name" : "Islam, Mohammed Sarul",
    "party" : 10
  },
  { "id" : 800,
    "name" : "Hitchinson, Rachael",
    "party" : 3
  },
  { "id" : 799,
    "name" : "Jones-Evans, Angela",
    "party" : 1
  }
],
"constituencies" : [ { "candidates" : [ 797,
        796,
        795,
        794,
        793,
        792,
        791
      ],
    "id" : 128,
    "name" : "Cardiff South and Penarth"
  },
  { "candidates" : [ 803,
        802,
        801,
        800,
        799,
        798
      ],
    "id" : 129,
    "name" : "Cardiff West"
  }
],
"parties" : [ { "abbreviation" : "Green",
    "id" : 7
  },
  { "abbreviation" : "Comm",
    "id" : 54
  },
  { "abbreviation" : "Ind",
    "id" : 11
  },
  { "abbreviation" : "UKIP",
    "id" : 4
  },
  { "abbreviation" : "PC",
    "id" : 10
  },
  { "abbreviation" : "LD",
    "id" : 3
  },
  { "abbreviation" : "C",
    "id" : 1
  },
  { "abbreviation" : "Lab",
    "id" : 2
  }
],
"responses" : [ { "candidate" : 796,
    "constituency" : 128,
    "id" : 1,
    "will_vote" : true
  },
  { "candidate" : 798,
    "constituency" : 129,
    "id" : 2,
    "will_vote" : true
  }
]
}
```

Here's my model:

```
Poll.Response = DS.Model.extend(
  willVote: DS.attr 'boolean'
  candidate: DS.belongsTo 'candidate'
  constituency: DS.belongsTo 'constituency'
)
```

When trying to load the data I get these errors:

> - Assertion failed: You specified a hasMany (candidate) on Poll.Response but candidate was not found
> - Assertion failed: Trying to sideload candidates on Poll.Response but the type doesn't exist.
> - Assertion failed: You specified a hasMany (constituency) on Poll.Response but constituency was not found.

I have searched high and low for explanations to these errors and I can't find a thing, and I'm particularly perplexed by how it says I specified a hasMany when I clearly haven't.

If I remove the associations from the JSON and the belongsTo lines it seems to work fine.

What am I doing wrong? I'd be enormously grateful for any help!

---

As requested by kingpin2k, here is my store file:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api/v1'

Poll.Store = DS.Store.extend(
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
)
```

And here are the other models:

```
Poll.Constituency = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  candidates: DS.hasMany 'candidate'
  responses: DS.hasMany 'response'
)

Poll.Candidate = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  responses: DS.hasMany 'response'
  constituency: DS.belongsTo 'constituency'
  party: DS.belongsTo 'party'
)
```

Comment: Shot in the dark but it might be related to the attribute names being pluralized forms of the model they reference.

Comment: Good idea, edited above to reflect that change, though sadly it makes no difference.

Comment: which adapter are you using, and can you include the candidate and constituency models

Comment: Added that extra info. Thanks for looking!

Comment: And are you really using Ember Data .12?

Comment: Didn't realise there was a newer version, or that you don't have to specify the revision. Have removed that line, no difference.

Comment: To be clear, I'm using ember-rails so the latest ember data is presumably being used.

Comment: coolio, Ill try and repo and letcha know

Comment: Will you toss in the party model as well, it appears to be working for me, are you using store.find('response')

Comment: I don't actually have a party model in ember yet. No errors about that as yet though!

Here's the route:

    Poll.ResponsesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
      model: ->
        @get('store').find('response')

Comment: Right, so I noticed that ember-data was mentioned in the debug output of your example and not in mine, so I made ember-rails update ember and ember-data and now it's working. Serves me right for assuming ember-data was installed!

Thanks for your help. If you want to make something along the lines of "make sure ember-data is actually installed, you idiot" an answer I'll give you the points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turned out that ember-data wasn't actually installed. If you see errors like I did, try running

> rails g ember:install --head

in order to get the latest versions of everything.

Thanks to kingpin2k for helping to rule out other possibilities!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is a two parter, one you've uncovered a bug in the error it's telling you, it says it can't find the `hasMany`, but that assertion applies to `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationships.

Meaning it can't find your other models (`Poll.Candidate` and `Poll.Constituency`).  I would verify that they are being included in the page.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/98/edit

Comment: Hmm, this might just be the tip, I'm surprised it doesn't yell when it tries to sideload the rest of the json

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure it will be useful to see a working version which doesn't look too dissimilar to what I've got. Candidate and constituency are indeed being included correctly.